# How to scrape img.src attribute programmatically?

Tags: web, web-scraping

I am scraping img.src attribute on a website.
This site loads images when user scroll mouse then the image tag is placed in the client area of a web browser.
I need a solution to scrape img.src without scroll mouse.
Is there a way to call an event of the img tag?

Comment: check [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org)

Comment: which website do you need to scrape?

Comment: I am going to scrape linkedin.com